# Can I use Modern Script Editor and JSOM to get items from a list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, script-editor-webpart

In SharePoint Online is it possible to get info from lists and users by adding Modern Script Editor Web Part to a page and writing javascript code?

I've found a few examples but none of them have worked so far.

This one for example:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37536.sharepoint-online-retrieve-list-items-from-sharepoint-list-using-javascript-object-model-jsom.aspx

And I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is impossible. JSOM can only be available in classic experience. Modern Script Editor has limited functionality.